# How to add a value to session array without loosing previous values?

Tags: php, symfony, session, symfony4

I am trying to create product listing page, each product has a link to add the product in 'cart' array session. links are like `?id=1`, `?id=2`, `?id=3` etc. by clicking each link I want to add it to array session without deleting previous ones. I use this:

```
if (!empty($_getvars['id'])) {
    $data[$_getvars['id']] = $_getvars['id'];
    $session->set('cart', $data);
} 
print("<pre>");
print_r($session->get('cart'));
```

I am using symfony session component with native session option. `$_getvars['id']` is actually like `$_GET['id']`. The problem of this code is that, I lost previous values and at each time, I have the latest selected id product in session. How to solve it?
I know a solution is like:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$_getvars['id']] = "...";
$_SESSION['cart'][$_getvars['id']] = "...";
```

but as I am using symfony session, how can I do this?

Comment: Check the Symphony docs on $session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need to retrieve it first:

```
if (!empty($_getvars['id'])) {

    $data = $session->get('cart');

    $data[$_getvars['id']] = $_getvars['id'];
    $session->set('cart', $data);
} 
print("<pre>");
print_r($session->get('cart'));
```

Comment: Thanks, May I ask your help for this one too please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58527391/how-to-increment-the-session-array-value @Arleigh Hix