# How to increment the session array value?

Tags: php, symfony, session, symfony4

I am using this on a shopping cart

```
if (!empty($_getvars['id'])) {
    $data = $session->get('cart');
    $data[] = $_getvars['id'];
    $session->set('cart', $data);
}
```

`$_getvars['id']` is productid, and on each click, a new array element will be added to the session. It works fine as it is now, but if a product is chosen more than once a new array will be added, how can change it that productid will be array offset and the value will be incremented from 1 each time to reflect the quantity?

```
$i = 1;
if (!empty($_getvars['id'])) {
    $data = $session->get('cart');
    $data[$_getvars['id']] = $i++;
    $session->set('cart', $data);
}
```

but this code each time resets to 1. How to fix it? Or any better array structure for a shopping cart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not set, set it to zero, then always add one.

```
if (!empty($_getvars['id'])) {
    $data = $session->get('cart');
    if(!isset($data[$_getvars['id']]){
        $data[$_getvars['id']] = 0;
    }
    $data[$_getvars['id']] += 1;
    $session->set('cart', $data);
}
```

Or you could add a dynamic quantity

```
if (!empty($_getvars['id'])) {
    $data = $session->get('cart');
    if(!isset($data[$_getvars['id']]){
        $data[$_getvars['id']] = 0;
    }
    // $_GET['qty'] OR 1, if not set
    $qty = (!empty($_getvars['qty']))? $_getvars['qty']: 1;
    $data[$_getvars['id']] += $qty;
    $session->set('cart', $data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58528052/how-to-get-the-current-session-array-count-in-twig @Arleigh Hix